# on android webview avoid or block unexpected open help center for cookies

Tags: android, webview

i have development a android app with web view but sometimes it opens the help center for cookies:

[image]

this is my configuration:

```
webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
```

how can i prevent this from happening?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this line after initialize your webview**

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```